# CSS Hover Inside Hover

Tags: css

So currently I have a fiddle like this -
`Please refer to the fiddle, its very difficult to explain with just code` https://jsfiddle.net/er8486hu/

What I am trying to do is when b is hovered over a returns to its oringial size. Is this possible using css?

Comment: With css you can only control the hover states of the object being hovered over, and any elements nested inside that object.  Since B is inside A, you can't control A through B's hover states (but you could do the opposite).  You would need to use Javascript to accomplish this.  With more info on why you want to accomplish this, it could be possible to arrange things differently and possibly find a css solution.

Comment: Can you please make this clear? `What I am trying to do is when b is hovered over a returns to its oringial size.`

Comment: What is supposed to return to its original size? A or B?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is when the blue square is hovered over, b, that the red square a, returns to its original size or scale. I am not sure if this is possible with css.

Comment: Can you explain again why you can't make a snippet? I'm not sure I follow your reasoning for not having code in the question.

Comment: @DawnPatrol You are only partly correct, it is also possible to control css properties of neighboring elements (`someelement:hover + neighborelement`) and sibling elements (`someelement:hover ~ siblingelements`). It is true though that you cannot "go up in the DOM" since there is no parent/ancestor selector in CSS.