# On hover menu doesnt wrap back

Tags: html, css

Trying to make CSS element in my web page.
On hover "Company", the div should slide from bottom, then on hover of green area it should wrap down.

So, the hover on green doesnt work.

Been truing several ways, should i use jquery for that?

No code here, i will give Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CapablancaYEAH/L90okw4q/

Please help me find mistake!

```
 <div class="content_positioner_bottom">
 <h4>COMPANY</h4>
 <span class="content_line">
 </span>
 <div class="wrap_menu"></div>
 <div id="closer" class="unwrap_menu">
 <div class="wrap_menu"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do parent modification using css only, you might need  some js for that

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928787/css-hover-inside-hover

Comment: Thank you, its established, that i for sure need jQuery, but i couldnt find a solution though

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) or [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) accordion to do this.

Comment: Oki, thats nice, do you know any specific example or code i can use?
With [close] button maybe? So on hover i get new element, then i can close it and that should be repeatable

Comment: With your current HTML, maybe something like this:
`$(".content_positioner_bottom").hover(function() {
 $(".wrap_menu").addClass("is-open");
});`

`$(".wrap_menu").hover(function() {
 $(".wrap_menu").removeCLass("is-open");
});`
And then put your open-styling in the css-class `.is-open`

Comment: Excuse me again, i made another fiddle on a basis of example.
http://jsfiddle.net/2juv5byq/1/
So, i need to edit jQuery code, so that red square wraps it all on hover, i`m not able to change existing code correctly. As i assume, i need to write 'div'  and #closer somewhere... Can you please tell?